# Liquid filter upcase adds [" "] to the filtered string

Tags: jekyll, liquid

i am filtering

```
{{ post.categories | upcase }}
```

but the output puts the string inside this [" "]

example ["TECH"] instead of just TECH.

Comment: Are you using liquid in Shopify or Jekyll or something else?

Comment: Im using liquid for jekyll

Answer (score 0):

`{{ post.categories }}` is an array so outputting it shows it as an array.

Add the data to your question if you need further clarification. What you should do instead is:

```
{% for category in post.categories %}
  {{ category }}
{% endfor %}
```